# SQL query or logic to implement search result

Tags: mysql, sql, salesforce, soql

I have a text box and search button same as stackoverflow, I have a field in database "Title", Now i want a sql query or some kind of logic which actually filter the string from "Title" field. 
Eg. if I type "**Stackoverflow is good website**" in a searchbox.

> Now I want those records from the table which contains
>   "**Stackoverflow**" OR "**is**" OR "**good**" OR "**website**".

I don't know if this is possible using a query or I have to write a logic. 
FYI I am using salesforce.

Comment: I actually thought of create a dynamic query in loop and add %   before and after every string and than put it into the query with 'LIKE' operation.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.  How did it turn out?

Comment: Its working fine. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I must have a reputation of 50 to comment so I'll post an answer instead. Using a dynamic query with the like comparison and or operator is the best method for the SOQL method. Depending on the size of your record sets I would look into front end solutions for better filtering methods. If you have several hundred results even, frameworks like angular or even custom solutions (show / hide) can create very nice user experiences with the data.